# Capturando informações do plaintext e guardando em variável

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber como faço para capturar números de um `plaintext` e guardar em uma variável.

Answer (score 1):

Quando diz `PlainText` você quis dizer um campo de texto? Segue um exemplo usando o **EditText**:

```
int i = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
```